# Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ and find $\operatorname{tr}(A)$.

Tags: matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ where $a_{ij}=u_iv_j$ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$ and $u_i,v_j$ are real numbers which satisfy $A^5=16A$ then find $\operatorname{tr}(A)$.

I can't solve this. Help!

Comment: The possible eigenvalues are $0,-2,2$

Comment: If you use neither punctuation nor the third singular person of the verb "to satisfy", the reader might be induced to believe that "which" stands for "real numbers", instead of "$A$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $A^2=B=[b_{ij}]_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$. You have
$$b_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^n u_iv_ku_kv_j=a_{ij}\text{tr}(A).$$
This shows $A^2=\text{tr}(A) A$ and by induktion $A^n=\text{tr}(A)^{n-1} A$ for $n\geq 2$. Thus you get $16=\text{tr}(A)^{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually quite simple. $A = \{a_{ij}\}$ and $a_{ij} = u_i v_j$. Therefore 
$$
(AA)_{ik} = a_{ij} a_{jk} = u_i v_j u_j v_k = (u_j v_j) u_i v_k \, ,
$$
where $u_j v_j = u \cdot v$ is the scalar product of vectors $u$ and $v$. Therefore
$$
(AAAA)_{il} = (u \cdot v) u_i v_k (u \cdot v) u_k v_l = (u \cdot v)^3 u_i v_l \, .
$$
Hence $(AAAAA)_{im} = (A^5)_{im} = (u \cdot v)^3 u_i v_l u_l v_m =  (u \cdot v)^4 u_i v_m$. The equation $A^5 = 16A$ can be written as $(u \cdot v)^4 u_i v_m = 16 u_i v_m$. For non-zero $u$ and $v$, I get $u \cdot v = 2$.

The trace is 
$$tr(A) = a_{ii} = u_i v_i = u \cdot v = 2 \, .
$$